# Refinery CMS - No route matches {:locale=>:en, :controller=>"refinery/news/items"} after navigating to http://localhost:3000/news

Tags: rubygems, content-management-system, refinerycms

I went through the process of installing refinerycms-news engine;

I added the refinerycms-news to my gemfile.

```
gem "refinerycms-news", '~> 2.0.0'
```

then ran

```
bundle install
rails generate refinery:news
rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

then restarted the server.

After refreshing, the "news" tab shows up in my backend but when I go to view the page on the front end at "http://localhost:3000/news" I get this error.

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:locale=>:en, :controller=>"refinery/news/items"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

The same thing happened after I tried install the refinerycms-inquiries gem as well.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the esame issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you've done something like either of these anywhere in your views:

```
<%= link_to some_page.title, some_page.url %>
<%= link_to some_page.title, some_page.url_normal %>
```

Change it to:

```
<%= link_to some_page.title, refinery.url_for(some_page) %>
```

You may also be able to use this if you're set on paths:

```
<%= link_to some_page.title, some_page.nested_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run the generator after adding the gem so that the pages table is seeded.

`rails g refinery:myextension`